# What is Eclipse SR1 package?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Recently, I was gonna download `Eclipse` from http://eclipse.org/downloads/. I noticed the recent package is `Eclipse Kepler (4.3.1) SR1 Packages`. I did some searches online but couldn't gather information about following questions.

- What does SR1 means?
- What are changes in Eclipse Kepler SR1 packages?

Any links or descriptions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here there is an explanation on the letters on Eclipse packages:
http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/build_types.html

SR means Service Release (aka Service Packs)- And is explained here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_release_life_cycle#Support

So, SR1 would be the first Service Release for Eclipse Kepler

**[EDIT]**

There are not Release Notes yet. But [here there is a bugfix list](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/buglist.cgi?bug_status=RESOLVED&bug_status=VERIFIED&bug_status=CLOSED&classification=Eclipse&classification=RT&product=Equinox&product=JDT&product=PDE&product=Platform&resolution=FIXED&target_milestone=4.3.1&order=bug_id) it may give you an idea what was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

SR means "Service Release". Quoting [this Eclipse wiki page](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Simultaneous_Release):

> Each year the Eclipse Foundation and its projects produce a release on
>   a coordinated schedule. This release is often referred to as the
>   simultaneous release, coordinated release, release train, or annual
>   release of Eclipse. [...] Each
>   release typically occurs in June, with **follow-up *service releases*** in
>   September (SR1) and February (SR2).

Emphasis is mine.

Comment: Thanks. Did you find any links that list the changes in recent SR1 release?

Comment: It depends on the component of the simultaneous release (JDT, CDT...). For instance, find the list of closed issues for JDT (Java) [here](http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/core/index.php)